# how the backups are going on automatically without Jobs,maintenance plan?

Tags: sql-server

In Sql server 2000 version I found there is daily full backups are going on for all databaeses at one particular time.
But I didn't found any maintainance plan or any job or any windows task schedule to take the backups.
Here my point is how the backups are going on automatically? I want to find out how? 
Please help

Comment: This is far too broad for anyone to provide a meaningful answer. My best guess is that there is some third party tool handling backups. Check with your IT department and/or DBA.

Comment: Sure I'll check with them meanwhile if there is any option please let me know
Thank you